# is it posible invoke another client method remotely?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-remoting

i would like to make an .net or even cross-platform(php, .net) app A and B that communicate each other. 
if A insert or update some data in database, then B is refresh its view to display new data. is there any solution about this?

i read this article about [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee958158(d=printer).aspx) before, as far as i know now client only call method that operate for them self. also that article mention that it can notify another client to do something but not specify how-to make 1 client inform another to call some method.

is there any tutorial or help regarding this problem? 
Thank you..

Comment: You can use the Azure IoT Hub to invoke methods, but I think it's to much for your project!?

Comment: Thak you sean for your suggestion.. I think so.. but it make me wanna know more about iot hub next time hehe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/596287/Broadcasting-Events-with-a-Duplex-WCF-Service

this link help me to do it.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There are two (easy) options:

1. You can use the Azure IoT Hub to invoke methods. I have successfully done it.
   [More about Azure IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-what-is-iot-hub)
2. If your goal is to generate a near real-time dashboard (report) you can use PowerPI with REST-API and a Push-/Streamingdataset. If you don't want to codding: [Look at this post](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/push-rows-to-a-power-bi-streaming-dataset-without-writing-any-code-using-microsoft-flow/)

Comment: Thanks sean for the answer. How you make the destination client to listen some command everytime?